# PHP json decode breaking when image tag present

Tags: php, ajax, json

Here is my json encoded string coming from a db query:

```
[{"columns":[{"class":"grid","html":"<p></p><img src="http://localhost/media/image.jpg"><p></p>"}]},{"columns":[{"class":"grid","html":""}]}]
```

When I go to json_decode in PHP I am getting NULL.

```
$content = json_decode($json_str); = NULL
```

I haven't had this issue before.  I am using JSON.stringify when saving the item into the db via ajax like so:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(html);
```

Do I have to start treating this differently for some reason?

Comment: The problem are the double quotes in the img tag. So either you change them to singlequotes or escape them before outputting.

Comment: Shouldn't the json stringify take care of that?

Comment: You can also check `json_last_error()` result code.

Comment: Perhaps. But clearly it doesn't.

Comment: If that JSON comes from DB, then it was inserted badly. Don't you have some necessary `stripslashes` before inserting data to DB?

Comment: @DennisFischer, the error function returns this JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX

Comment: @K_G That's what we already knew :). You're doing something wrong inside the javascript code. We can't see it we can't help. Look at this jsFiddle working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4RvLm/